# VBA, SQL, Queries

Tags: sql, vba

I have an access form with few controls on it, like `start-date`, `end-date`, `move_type`, `mover_name` etc, when user fills this field n clicks on query command button, a select query is run and it fetches records from various tables depending upon the criteria mentioned by the user.

Later the same records are exported to excel file and a report is generated for user.

Now I need to do more with this, my select query has a field "quoted-price", depending upon the price quoted the records need to be sorted out.

**EX :** if `quoted_price < 500` then it is a "domestic apartment1", if `quoted-price` is >500 And <1500 it is "domestic Apartment1" etc.

Now I need to do more with this, my select query has a field "quoted-price", depending upon the price quoted the records need to be sorted out.

**EX :** if `quoted_price < 500` then it is a "domestic apartment1", if quoted-price is >500 And <1500 it is "domestic Apartment1" etc. and when all the records generated through select query are searched on this criteria, the records need to be grouped accordingly. Later the count for individual category is multiplied by a unit value and total charge is calculated.

I tried building many queries to do this and tables to refer to value but of no use. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Show us your queries and schemas that you have tried.

Comment: I haven't tried anything realy for the second part of my query, its so confusing, but as long as first select query is concern it works fine

Answer (score 0):

are you looking to create a new field depending on the condition? That may be step one of what you are trying to do, If so that is pretty easy. See here: http://allenbrowne.com/casu-14.html

Comment: ok i created another query, to retrieve "quoted_price" from my first query, and m able to add a new field to the query but now, how do i assigned an alias to my "move_type" field. if quoted_price < 500 then it is a "domestic apartment1", if quoted-price is >500 And <1500 it is "domestic Apartment1" etc.

Comment: same thing new field with value depending on a IIF statement It may be a bunch of code but it sounds like what you want, you may need to do it in a subsequent query ie a query on a query